# Минимальный гамильтонов циклов для каждого подмножества вершин графа

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Имеется граф с `n` вершинами, необходимо для каждого подмножества вершин (всего 2<sup>n</sup> подмножеств) найти длину минимального простого цикла, проходящего через каждую вершину подмножества.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(А). Сначала решим задачу нахождения минимальной длины всех простых циклов, содержащих вершину ноль (нумерация вершин с нуля). Воспользуемся [динамическим программированием](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Будем рассматривать простые пути из вершины ноль в вершину `i`:

`0` = `v1` → `v2` → ... →  `vk-1` → `vk` = `i`

Нам не важно в каком именно порядке были посещены вершин, поэтому будет хранить только битовую маску посещённых вершин (то есть число `mask` от нуля (включительно) до 2<sup>число вершин</sup> (невключительно), такое что его `i`-ый бит равен единице ⇔ была посещена вершина `i`). Заведём двумерный массив:

`dp[i][mask]` — минимальная длина простого пути из вершины ноль в вершину `i`, проходящего через вершины, задаваемые битовой маской `mask`.

Изначально `dp[0][20] = 0`, остальные элементы равны бесконечности. Сделаем динамику вперёд: будем перебирать последнюю вершину и маску посещённых вершин и пытаться пойти в каждую из непосещённых вершин. Также будем обновлять ответ — путём замыкания пути, то есть добавления ребра `последняя вершина` → `стартовая вершина`.

Работает это за `O(n2 * 2n)`

---

(Б). Теперь решим исходную задачу. Можно было бы перебрать каждую вершину и решить задачу (А) с этой вершиной в качестве стартовой, получилось бы `O(n3 * 2n)`.

Но так ответ для каждого подмножества будет считаться несколько раз — по разу для каждой вершины, входящей в подмножество (когда эта вершина была исходной). Можно этого избежать, сделав так, чтобы для каждого подмножества была выделенная исходная вершина. Например, в качестве неё можно взять вершину с максимальным номером.

Таким образом, мы будем перебирать каждую вершину, запускать алгоритм из пункта (А) с этой вершиной в качестве стартовой, но будем рассматривать только пути, проходящие через вершины с номерами меньшими номера стартовой вершины. Так мы обеспечим, что ответ для каждого подмножества будет подсчитан один раз.

Работает это за [image] [=](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%20k%5E2%20*%202%5Ek) `O(n2 * 2n)`

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // считаем что граф является полным и вводится с клавиатуры,
    // сначала число вершин n,
    // затем матрица смежности графа (квадратная матрица размера n) 
    int number_vertexes;
    cin >> number_vertexes;
    vector<vector<double>> distances(number_vertexes, vector<double>(number_vertexes));
    for (vector<double> &line : distances) {
        for (double &distance : line) {
            cin >> distance;
        }
    }

    // подмножество задаётся битовой маской из диапозона [0, 2^n)
    // i-ый бит равен единице ↔ вершина i входит в подмножество
    int mask_count = 1 << number_vertexes;
    const double max_double = numeric_limits<double>::max();
    // answer[mask] == ответ для подмножества, задаваемого mask
    vector<double> answer(mask_count, max_double);
    // ответ для пустого подмножества точек --- ноль
    answer[0] = 0;

    for (int start_point = 0; start_point < number_vertexes; ++start_point) {
        // чтобы не считать ответ для каждой подмаски много раз
        // выберем для каждой подмаски стартовой вершниу --- вершину с наибольшим номером
        // таким образом для стартовой вершины i можем считать что существуют только вершины [0..i-1]
        // это значительно ускорит перебор
        int number_points_current = start_point + 1;
        int mask_count_current = 1 << number_points_current;

        // для каждой вершины start_point посчитаем динамику:
        // dp[i][mask] --- минимальная длина простого пути из вершины start_point в вершину i,
        // проходящего через вершины, задаваемые битовой маской mask
        // (start_point и i входят в mask)
        vector<vector<double>> dp(number_points_current, vector<double>(mask_count_current, max_double));
        dp[start_point][1 << start_point] = 0;

        // динамика вперёд: перебираем последнюю вершину и маску посещённых вершин,
        for (int mask = 0; mask < mask_count_current; ++mask) {
            for (int last_point = 0; last_point < number_points_current; ++last_point) {
                // если существует путь из начальной вершины в последнюю
                if (dp[last_point][mask] != max_double) {
                    // пытаемся пойти из последней вершину в каждую, ещё не посещённую
                    for (int next_point = 0; next_point < number_points_current; ++next_point) {
                        if ((mask & (1 << next_point)) == 0) {
                            int next_mask = mask | (1 << next_point);
                            double next_distance = dp[last_point][mask] + distances[last_point][next_point];
                            dp[next_point][next_mask] = min(dp[next_point][next_mask], next_distance);
                        }
                    }

                    // пытаемся пойти из последней вершину в стартовую, то есть замкнуть путь
                    double next_distance = dp[last_point][mask] + distances[last_point][start_point];
                    answer[mask] = min(answer[mask], next_distance);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // как-нибудь используем полученный массив answer

    return 0;
}
```